# SQL Server making groups

Tags: sql, sql-server

I have a query:

```
select maand, KENMART, minprio, _Id, rij 
from Tabelx
```

with this output:

```
maand   KENMART     minprio _Id     Rij
----------------------------------------
201701  15959074    29      2921957 1   
201702  15959074    29      2921957 2  
201703  15959074    29      2921957 3  
201704  15959074    29      2921957 4  
201705  15959074    29      2921957 5  
201706  15959074    29      2921957 6  
201707  15959074    29      2921955 1  
201708  15959074    29      2921955 2  
201709  15959074    19      2921949 1  
201710  15959074    19      2921949 2  
201711  15959074    19      2921949 3   
201712  15959074    29      2921953 1  
201801  15959074    29      2921951 1  
201802  15959074    19      2921947 1  
201803  15959074    19      2921947 2  
201804  15959074    29      2921951 2  
201805  15959074    29      2921951 3  
201806  15959074    29      2921951 4  
201807  15959074    29      2921951 5  
201808  15959074    29      2921951 6  
201809  15959074    29      2921951 7
```

I want to make groups so my output looks like this

```
maand   KENMART     minprio _Id     Rij Group     
-----------------------------------------------
201701  15959074    29      2921957 1   A   
201702  15959074    29      2921957 2   A    
201703  15959074    29      2921957 3   A    
201704  15959074    29      2921957 4   A    
201705  15959074    29      2921957 5   A    
201706  15959074    29      2921957 6   A    
201707  15959074    29      2921955 1   B   
201708  15959074    29      2921955 2   B    
201709  15959074    19      2921949 1   C    
201710  15959074    19      2921949 2   C    
201711  15959074    19      2921949 3   C   
201712  15959074    29      2921953 1   D    
201801  15959074    29      2921951 1   E    
201802  15959074    19      2921947 1   F     
201803  15959074    19      2921947 2   F    
201804  15959074    29      2921951 2   G   
201805  15959074    29      2921951 3   G    
201806  15959074    29      2921951 4   G    
201807  15959074    29      2921951 5   G    
201808  15959074    29      2921951 6   G    
201809  15959074    29      2921951 7   G
```

the problem is with this group

```
201801 15959074 29 2921951 1 E
```

it has the same ID as group G but has to be a different group because the months do not align.

I hope the question is clear and you guys can help me out.

Thanks in advance

Comment: Can you explain the logic for defining the groups?  And I see no column called "month", so your explanation doesn't help.

Comment: In addition to what Gordon wrote, sample data is best served as [DDL](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Data_definition_language) + [DML](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Data_manipulation_language). Please [edit] your question to include it, your current attempt and your desired results. For more details, [read this.](https://dba.meta.stackexchange.com/questions/2976/help-me-write-this-query-in-sql)

Answer (score 1):

Here is the code and its working fine.i have used the numeric statement for testing purpose for example A is '1' B is '2' and so on.

```
select *,(
(case
 when KENMART = 15959074 and id=2921957 then 1 
 when KENMART = 15959074 and id=2921955 then 2
 when KENMART = 15959074 and id=2921949 then 3
 when KENMART = 15959074 and id=2921953 then 4
 when KENMART = 15959074 and id=2921947 then 5
 when KENMART = 15959074 and id=2921951 then 6

end) ) as [Group]
 from tabelx
```

Answer (score 0):

I'm pretty sure this is a gaps-and-islands problem.  One method uses `lag()` and a cumulative sum:

```
select t.*,
       sum(case when _id = prev_id then 0 else 1 end) over (partition by kenmart order by maand) as grp
from (select t.*,
             lag(_id) over (partition by kenmart order by maand) as prev_id
      from tabelx t
     ) t;
```

This constructs the groupings as numbers, rather than letters.